# Is there any possible connection between Gamma Ray Burst and Fast Radio Bursts?

Tags: gamma-ray-bursts, fast-radio-bursts

The physical nature of **Fast Radio Bursts** (***FRBs***), a new type of ***cosmological transients*** discovered recently, is not known. It has been suggested that ***FRBs*** can be produced when a ***spinning supra-massive neutron star loses centrifugal support*** and ***collapses to a black hole***.

Here we suggest that such implosions can happen in supra-massive neutron stars shortly (hundreds to thousands of seconds) after their births, and an ***observational signature of such implosions*** may have been observed in the ***X-ray afterglows*** of some long and short **Gamma-Ray Bursts** (***GRBs***).

Under this picture, a small fraction of *FRBs* would be physically connected to *GRBs*. Is there any possible connection between ***[Gamma Ray Bursts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma-ray_burst)*** and ***[Fast Radio Bursts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_radio_burst)*** ??

Comment: who's 'we'? if your suggestion is copied from a paper it would be useful to have a link to it. It may provide the best current answer to your question

Comment: Happy to say, you should take a look at http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2017arXiv170102370M from today's AstroPH!

Answer (score 1):

There is a tentative detection of a GRB simultaneously with an FRB,  [DeLaunay et al 2016](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/2041-8205/832/1/L1/meta). If it is true, it would mean that at least some FRBs have the same origin as some GRBs.

Theoretically many possibilities were suggested before and after this tentative, detection. For now they all remain quite speculative, and more observations are required (and planned)
For some selection of models, it could be interesting to look into [citations](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-ref_query?bibcode=2016ApJ...832L...1D&refs=CITATIONS&db_key=AST) to this paper or its [references](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-ref_query?bibcode=2016ApJ...832L...1D&refs=REFERENCES&db_key=AST).